# EAGLView with CGAffineTransform problem on iOS 4.3

Tags: opengl-es, cgaffinetransform, ios4, eaglview

I have a weird problem with OpenGL on iOS 4.3.
I have a ViewController with some views and images in the foreground. In the background I have an EAGLView drawn from a CGImage. 
When I try to pinch, pan or rotate the EAGLView (not the OpenGL object, just the view) with CGAffineTransform and GestureRecognizer, the view sometimes starts blinking.
On iOS 4.2 and other older iOS versions it works fine.
Can anybody help me?